# Sample Rate Harmonics in a Multi-Rate System

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, finite-impulse-response

I've observed an interesting phenomena in a system I am working on that almost seems intuitive, but I don't have a good explanation of. I'm hoping someone can offer an explanation of what's happening.

I have a device that samples at 5 MHz. This data is filtered with an FIR filter to about 80% of Nyquist. The output of this filter is given to another FIR filter and then decimated by 1 /16, for an effective sample rate of 5e6 S/s / 16 = 312.5 kS/s. If I take an FFT of this output, after collecting a block of samples, I see a strong signal at the (block_length * 5 MHz)^-1, and all it's harmonics (even and odd). In other words, I'm seeing the sample rate of the "burst", at the faster sample rate, in the lower sample rate.

Can anyone put a name to what's happening here?

EDIT: I'll add that this is a real device, subject to real, physical happenings.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the signal sampled at 5 MHz?  What is the bandwidth of your lowpass FIR, is it 1 MHz? What about the second FIR before decimation? There is a probability of aliasing

Comment: Be aware that performing a digital filter directly after sampling your signal is not sufficient to prevent aliasing. Your input analog signal needs to be low-pass filtered (e.g. RC filter) with a cutoff lower than Nyquist before quantization. How much lower depends on the roll-off rate and accepted transition region that can be discarded. Many DAQs will do this filtering for you, but it would be good to verify.

Comment: The bandwidth of the first FIR is 2.5 MHz. The second (pre decimation) is 156.25 KHz.